# Copying from one IEnumerable list to another not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through one enumerable list and populate another empty enumerable list. So basically the first list contains Enumerable list of the entity class and I am trying to populate my viewmodel with this his list. For some reason I cant see the values getting assigned to the viewmodel list though I can see the entity list containing values. What am i doing wrong

```
var fundClasses = GetService<FUND_CLASS>().Where(x => x.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS.FUND_ID == id);

IEnumerable<AccountingFundClassesViewModel> accountingFundClassesViewModel = new List<AccountingFundClassesViewModel>();

foreach (var fc in fundClasses)
{
    foreach (var af in accountingFundClassesViewModel)
    {
        af.Id = fc.ID;
        af.Description = fc.DESCRIPTION;
        af.InvestedAmount = fc.INVESTED_AMMOUNT;
        af.InceptionDate = fc.INCEPTION_DATE;
        af.LegalFundClassId = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID;
        af.DataReference = fc.DATA_REFERENCE;
        af.CogencyClassId = fc.COGENCY_CLASS_ID;
        af.ClosureStatusId = fc.CLOSURE_STATUS_ID;
        af.IsSidePocket = fc.IS_SIDE_POCKET;
        af.IsThematic = fc.IS_THEMATIC;
        af.VehicleTypeId = fc.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID;
    }
}

var vm = new TermsCondtionsViewModel
{
    accountingFundClassesViewModel = accountingFundClassesViewModel
};

return vm;
```

Viewmodels

```
public class TermsCondtionsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<AccountingFundClassesViewModel> accountingFundClassesViewModel;

    public FundTermsViewModel fundTermsViewModel;

    public LegalFundClassesViewModel legalFundClassesViewModel;
}


public class AccountingFundClassesViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? InvestedAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InceptionDate { get; set; }
    public int? LegalFundClassId { get; set; }
    public int? DataReference { get; set; }
    public int? CogencyClassId { get; set; }
    public int? ClosureStatusId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSidePocket { get; set; }
    public bool IsThematic { get; set; }
    public int? VehicleTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are iterating over `accountingFundClassesViewModel` which is empty.

Comment: You're never adding any items to `accountingFundClassesViewModel`. I suspect your `foreach (var af in accountingFundClassesViewModel)` loop shouldn't be a loop at all, but should just be adding a new item to `accountingFundClassesViewModel`. Or just use LINQ instead to "select" the new view model.

Comment: Could you show me an example Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are enumerating over `accountingFundClassesViewModel` which is empty.
What you want is to iterate the array that contains data and create a new model to populate and then add to your new list.

```cs
foreach (var fc in fundClasses)
{
    var af = new AccountingFundClassesViewModel
    {
        Id = fc.ID,
        Description = fc.DESCRIPTION,
        InvestedAmount = fc.INVESTED_AMMOUNT,
        InceptionDate = fc.INCEPTION_DATE,
        LegalFundClassId = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID,
        DataReference = fc.DATA_REFERENCE,
        CogencyClassId = fc.COGENCY_CLASS_ID,
        ClosureStatusId = fc.CLOSURE_STATUS_ID,
        IsSidePocket = fc.IS_SIDE_POCKET,
        IsThematic = fc.IS_THEMATIC,
        VehicleTypeId = fc.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID,
    };

    accountingFundClassesViewModel.Add(af);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `LINQ` as @Jon mentioned in his comment..

```cs
var accountingFundClassesViewModel = fundClasses.Select(fc => new AccountingFundClassesViewModel{
        Id = fc.ID,
        Description = fc.DESCRIPTION,
        InvestedAmount = fc.INVESTED_AMMOUNT,
        InceptionDate = fc.INCEPTION_DATE,
        LegalFundClassId = fc.LEGAL_FUND_CLASS_ID,
        DataReference = fc.DATA_REFERENCE,
        CogencyClassId = fc.COGENCY_CLASS_ID,
        ClosureStatusId = fc.CLOSURE_STATUS_ID,
        IsSidePocket = fc.IS_SIDE_POCKET,
        IsThematic = fc.IS_THEMATIC,
        VehicleTypeId = fc.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: If i am using the linq one then how to i assign it to accountingFundClassesViewModel in the TermsCondtionsViewModel

Comment: @Tom Call `.ToList()` on it or change the type to `IEnumerable<TermsCondtionsViewModel>`